Role of "that" in "Where are some places in your neighborhood that people like to hang out?"
Where are some places in your neighborhood that people like to hang out?
I think "that" introduces the subordinating adverb clause in the sentence above, and can be replaced with "where" or omited. Am I right?

It's called a "relativizer", but it doesn't really have much of a "function" or "meaning", since it's syntactically fine not to include it at all, and it makes no difference to the meaning. Same as "Name a city [that] you've visited".

that is expendable.  This is perfectly understandable to native speakers: Where are some places in your neighborhood people like to hang out?  {there, "hang out" = spend time in.]   that tells us explicitly that people like to hang out describes "places in your neighborhood".

... or "Tell me something [that] I don't know". By way of showing [that] it's just chance that that seems to carry the same "meaning" as where in your example. Syntactically, my that here and yours in the example are the same.

Hi Tim, you said "hang out" = spend time in, but we say people like to hand out in the neighborhood. Is it right to just say people like to hand out the neighborhood?

"hand out" is nothing to do with "hang out". Ever

Sorry, it's a typo.

I do not understand why you said "but".  What is the contradiction you are trying to bring to my attention?  If you are asking if it is the noun "neighborhood" that is being described by the relative clause, the answer is no.  "in your neighborhood" is a locative adjunct specifying where those "places" are.  Compare "They showed us a picture of a flag on the moon that is red, white, and blue".

No, it isn't correct to say that people 'like to hang out the neighbourhood', so I would prefer where - but people don't always use logical grammar in casual speech. (Hang out in this sense is an informal expression).

The relativiser that can be omitted:

Where are some places in your neighborhood [ ] people like to hang out [at]?

We need a preposition because the phrasal verb hang out used in this sense is intransitive and needs a preposition if we want to specify some places, as what the question expects.  (For information, the transitive use is usually for describing hanging out something, for example, banners or washed clothing.)
Cambridge Dictionary
has several examples for hang out used in this sense: informal B1  to spend a lot of time in a place or with someone:

You still hang out at the pool hall?

Also we have examples like this from Collins Dictionary: PHRASAL VERB B2

I often used to hang out in supermarkets.

As described in the dictionaries, the phrasal verb is for informal use.
For the OP's example, we can also use the relative adverb where instead of that, and in this case at is not needed:

Where are some places in your neighborhood [where] people like to hang out?


Where are some places in your neighborhood [at which] people like to hang out?

We can bring at to the back and omit the relative pronoun which.
